# Configuring Apache2.2 + mod_ssl; need an explanation, not a how-to

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, openssl

N00b question, sorry:

I installed Apache 2.2.17 + OpenSSL on a Windows box, and now I'm trying to configure mod_ssl, but I can't. What I did was the following:

1. Using OpenSSL, create a certificate (`C:\my\cert`) and a key (`C:\my\key`).
2. Uncomment the line `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` in the `httpd.config` file.
3. Update `extra\httpd.ssl.conf`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   DocumentRoot "C:/my/document/root"
   # ...
   SSLEngine on
   # ...
   SSLCertificateFile "C:/my/cert"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/my/key"
   # ...
   <Location />
       SSLRequireSSL
   </Location>
   SSLOptions +StrictRequire
   ```

And, at this point, I am stuck. Please someone not only tell me what I have to do, but explain me why I have to do it.

---

The following line gets added to the `errors.log` file whenever I try to enter `https://mysite/`:

```
[Mon Mar 21 16:49:57 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.14] Invalid method in request \x16\x03
```

Comment: I assume Apache fails to start. Can we have the error message from your error log?

Comment: @Bittrance: Apache does not fail to start, but `https://mysite/` fails to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is

```
SSLEngine on
```

Inside that `<VirtualHost>` which is what tells Apache that it needs to process incoming connections as SSL connections.  Without it, Apache assumes that incoming connections are unencrypted and it tries to parse the SSL protocol as HTTP and gets gibberish.

Comment: I already set `SSLEngine on`, `SSLOptions +StrictRequire`, and `SSLRequireSSL`, yet still nothing happens.

Comment: My mistake was forgetting to include `httpd-ssl.conf` in `httpd.conf`. Sorry!